# VBA Split function, what would a blank function display as?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the split function in my code to separate "1.2 - 1.3" into two number, in two cells i.e. 1.2. and 1.3. I am doing this using the below code.

```
split1 = Split(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(SR, 1).Value, " - ")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(SR, 26).Value = split1(0)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(SR, 27).Value = split1(1)
```

However the cell can also hold just one value, such as "1.1" or "Unknown". 
What would the functions split(0) and split(1) become in these cases? 
I want to right an if statement for when this occurs, so that (SR, 26) is the same as (SR, 1) in this case and (SR, 27) is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will throw an error for split1(1). Split1(0) will return the value you have inserted in. You can catch those exception with

```
if ubound(split) =  0 then ....
```